# Arabic font not connected issue (niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf - mPdf)

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, mpdf, laravel-5.4

I am using the new mpdf version but it's showing separate Arabic characters
Currently showing

[image]

the correct word is
الإسم

Comment: try changing fonts. I had good results with tcpdf and font called "freesans"

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue with just add 2 new parameters in Arabic fonts array in pdf.php config file

```
'useOTL' => 0xFF,
'useKashida' => 75,


 'arabic-font' => [
     'R'  => 'arabic-font.ttf',    // regular font
     'B'  => 'arabic-font.ttf',          // optional: bold font
     'I'  => 'arabic-font-Light.ttf',    // optional: italic font
     'BI' => 'arabic-font.ttf',           // optional: bold-italic font
     'useOTL' => 0xFF,
     'useKashida' => 75,
]
```